# Passing an integer to a function asking for reference

Tags: c++

Why is this code well-formed? I'm not passing a reference to the function:

```
void function(const int& ref) {

}

int main()
{
    function(1);
}
```

Comment: `const ` in the function parameter signature allows you to do so. Try to omit it, and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can create a temporary from the constant and temporaries are allowed to bind to const references. If the reference wasn't const, this wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: The poor compiler didn't ask to be part of this discussion. It's just doing what the language rules tell it to :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, the compiler could create a temporary and bind it to a non-const reference, but it won't do that because the language rules tell it not to. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Constant lvalue references can bind to rvalues. Rvalues, like your literal `1`, don't have a persistent alias, so if you were to modifying it, you wouldn't be able to observe the effect, but if you promise not to modify it (namely by accessing it through a constant reference), you can still have perfectly sensible code, and that's why this binding is allowed.

(You can also bind rvalues to (mutable) *rvalue references*: `void function(int &&)` In that case, the rvalue reference becomes the (unique) alias of the value.)

Note also that without this rule it would be impossible to initialize variables from functions that return prvalues, or use copy-initialization at all:

```
struct T { T(int); };

T f();

T x = 1;     // ===  "T x = T(1);", copy constructor wants to bind to prvalue
T x = f();   // ditto
T x((f()));  // ditto
```

Comment: I don't get this last "copy-initialization" link with "being able to bind a constant lvalue reference with rvalues". I believe T(int) should have been T(const int&)

Comment: @user3834459: No, the `int` there has nothing to do with your int. The `T` value is the prvalue in this example.

Comment: I just don't get it how copy-initialization is related to the problem I just brought